# Sprite Opacity using OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, opacity, alpha-transparency, point-sprites

I'm trying to get my point sprites to display with the correct opacity.

Originally, I was getting my sprite texture on a black square.

So, I added the following to my fragment shader:

```
"if(color.a < 0.5) "+
               "discard;"+
```

Now, this does seem to work, in that my sprite displays without the black background, however, my texture itself is 'partially transparent' - and it isn't showing this partial transparency, it is appearing solid.  It's a bit difficult to explain, but I hope you understand what I mean.  If I draw the same texture using canvas/surfaceview, it displays correctly.

Basically I'm trying to get my textures to display in their original format (ie as they do in the software in which they were created - ie, the Gimp / photoshop etc).

Would appreciate any help - thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First make sure your textures are loaded from transparent pngs through a [`Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) with either `RGBA_8888` or `RGBA_4444` configuration, so you don't lose the alpha channel.

Second you need to enable `GL_BLEND` with the [`glEnable()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnable.xml) command. On Android you will write it like this: `GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);`. This allows you to blend the already drawn color with the new color, achieving a transparent look.
The blending function should be set to <s>[`GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_ALPHA`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) for regular transparency: `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`</s>
[`GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_ALPHA`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) for regular transparency: `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Finally, you do not need to use discard, just set the `gl_FragColor` to a 4-component vector with the alpha in the fourth channel (which is what you get when reading a texture from a sampler), e.g. you could just do `gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, texCoord);` if you wanted to.

You will most likely have to turn off depth-testing with `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` to avoid problems with unsorted triangles.

You can read a little bit more about transparency [here](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transparency.htm).

Comment: Thanks @Jave, I used your suggestions, I've removed the discard part of the Fragment Shader and although there is now no black box, it doesn't look right still - the texture is now 'transparent' but there is a dark outline around it and the image is duller than it should be - (Too transparent??) Would be grateful if you have any other suggestions - thanks

Comment: I figured it out - I needed to use GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); along with your suggestion - thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: wouldn't transparency based on alpha channel be glBlendFunc(GL_APLHA,  GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), from example section of the documentation, https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glBlendFunc.xhtml